# "The meeting ends in 2 hours" or "The meeting will ends in 2 hours"?

Tags: grammaticality

2 hours later is in the future, so "the meeting will ends in 2 hours" is correct, right? But since we say "the train arrives at 9AM", does "the meeting ends in 2 hours" make sense too?

Answer (score 1):

Valid forms are:

> - The meeting ends in 2 hours.
> - the meeting will end in 2 hours
> - The train arrives at 9 am.
> - The train will arrive at 9 am.

The will-form in the 2nd and 4th examples above is actually the [simple future tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/simple-future/). It uses "will" followeed by the root form of the verb. In regular verbs, (and many irregular ones as well) the root form is the same as the singular present form. The root form is always the form used after "to" in the **infinitive**.

Thus "the meeting will ends in 2 hours" is incorrect, because "ends" is not the root form of the ven "to end".

The first and third form above use the simple present to discuss the future. In this usage, a third-person plural form is used.

These two forms can usuallyt be used interchangably. The simple future lays more emphasis on the fact that the event will happen in the future, the other emphasizes the event. But the difference is subtle, and native or fluent speakers may use either form without much considering the difference.

Also valid, when, say, watching a movie:

> - The plane crashes in the next scene.
> - The plane will crash in the next scene.

Discussing a visit:

> - Frank will go home on Tuesday.
> - Frank goes home on Tuesday.